# Code is timeout - Hamming Number

Tags: javascript, mathematics

I have a problem with my code, because his is required a long time to be done(only when I put big numbers like 2000)...
I am trying to do the [*Hamming Numbers* kata on codewars.com](https://www.codewars.com/kata/526d84b98f428f14a60008da):

> A Hamming number is a positive integer of the form 2<sup>i</sup>3<sup>j</sup>5<sup>k</sup>, for some non-negative integers i, j, and k.
>
> Write a function that computes the nth smallest Hamming number.
>
> Specifically:
>
> - The first  smallest Hamming number is 1 = 2<sup>0</sup>3<sup>0</sup>5<sup>0</sup>
> - The second smallest Hamming number is 2 = 2<sup>1</sup>3<sup>0</sup>5<sup>0</sup>
> - The third  smallest Hamming number is 3 = 2<sup>0</sup>3<sup>1</sup>5<sup>0</sup>
> - The fourth smallest Hamming number is 4 = 2<sup>2</sup>3<sup>0</sup>5<sup>0</sup>
> - The fifth  smallest Hamming number is 5 = 2<sup>0</sup>3<sup>0</sup>5<sup>1</sup>
>
> The 20 smallest Hamming numbers are given in example test fixture.
>
> Your code should be able to compute all of the smallest 5,000 (Clojure: 2000, NASM: 13282) Hamming numbers without timing out.

And my code is:

```
function isHumming(x){
    while(x % 2 === 0) x /= 2;
    while(x % 3 === 0) x /= 3;
    while(x % 5 === 0) x /= 5;
    return x == 1;
}

function hamming (n){
    let duzina = 1;
    let trenutni = 2;
    let poslednji = 1;
    while(duzina < n){
        if(isHumming(trenutni)){
            if(trenutni >= n){
                poslednji = trenutni;
            }
            duzina++;
        }
        trenutni++
    }
    return poslednji;
}
console.log(hamming(100));
```

The problem arises when I try to put a large number like 5000, because the code seems stuck...Can anyone help me to create code which can do that in max 12 sec?

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. You check each "positive integer" for being a *Hamming number*. An alternative approach is to consider (first idea: generate) Hamming numbers only and find a way to handle *nth smallest*.

Comment: It would help a lot if you translated your variable names into English.